# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module polmgr due to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Error in Chrome Developers Tool

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module polmgr due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module polmgr.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $http due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$http' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This error is coming when i add $http to my module in ionicframework. 
I am noob.
I have added the $http in controllers.js file and if i remove everything works fine. but i need to make a http get call.

Find the controllers.js code below :-

```
angular.module('polmgr.controllers', ['$http'])

    .controller('PolicyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
     });
```

Correct Code:-

```
angular.module('polmgr.controllers', [])

    .controller('PolicyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of things you are trying to inject the `$http` service incorrectly.

It is part of the core `ng` module that `angular.js/angular.min.js` provides.

So you *don't* need to add it as a module dependency like this:

```
var ctrlModule = angular.module('polmgr.controllers', [..., '$http', ...])
```

Instead, just inject it into your controller functions like you would do for `$scope`:

```
.controller('PolicyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
});
```